# Closed for the motion of an interacting particle system

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

I am dealing with interacting particle systems approximately in the sense of http://www.math.vu.nl/~rmeester/onderwijs/Interacting_Particle_Systems/liggett.pdf p. 5 except I am reading a book by the same author, for which these notes act as mostly a summary.  As a summary of that summary, we have that the state space is $X=\{0, 1\}^S$ and we have nonnegative, uniformly bounded, rates of transition $c(x, \eta)$ which satisfy a convergence condition and are continuous in $\eta$ for each fixed $x$.  (It would be unreasonable for me to develop all the theory of the first 1/3 of the textbook here, but if there is a way to better ask this question for this website please let me know.)

I have come across the question multiple times of establishing that if $W$ is Borel in $X$, with transition rates "going out of W" all 0, then $W$ is closed for the motion of the interacting particle system. (That is to say that for the Feller process one obtains from the generator described in those notes, if you start in $W$ then almost surely for all time you stay in $W$.)  The more rigorous statement of the hypothesis would be that "whenever $\eta \in W$ and $\eta^x$ which is $\eta$ flipped in coordinate $x$ is not in $W$ then $c(x, \eta)=0$."

The issues here are mostly technicalities that I cannot resolve, having to do with the fact that $W$ may not be a finite dimensional cylinder.  When it is not, then one has trouble doing the usual argument that relates infinitessimal rates to "for all time" claims, because one cannot apply the generator to the indicator of $W$, which may not even be continuous on $X$.  There are special cases in which particular $W$ can be written as a nice union of finite dimensional sets, and then doing a double approximation argument suffices, but this does not appear to me to work for general $W$s or even all $W$s that are $F-\sigma$s.

Comment: To clarify what this general idea is, which fails because of technicalities, as I alluded to in the last paragraph, one generally tries to write down the indicator of $W$. Then one makes the connection that having $0$ transition rates going out of $W$ necessitates that if $\Omega$ is the generator, then $\Omega(1_W) \le 0$.  And then one uses the Banach space version of the fundamental theorem of calculus to discover that if $S_t$ is the corresponding semigroup, then $S_t(1_W)$ is decreasing, and hence if it starts out at $0$ at a point it must still be $0$ there at later times.

Comment: Did you try approximating $W$ from below with some 'good' sets?